# Infinite Loop error in my assignment; don't know how to fix

Tags: javascript

My task is to create a function **using while loops** that converts all e's in a sentence to a 3, and all a's to a 4. 'Hacker Speak'. My function right now puts the browser into an infinite loop. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```js
function hackerSpeak() {
  var sentence2 = document.getElementById('sentence2').value;
  var milk = false;
  var counting = 0;
  while (!milk) {
    if (counting == sentence2.value) {
      milk = true;
    } else if (sentence2.charCodeAt(counting) == "e") {
      sentence2.replace(counting, "3")
      counting++;
    } else if (sentence2.charCodeAt(counting) == "a") {
      sentence2.replace(counting, "4")
      counting++;
    } else {
      counting++;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('replaceThree').innerHTML = sentence2;
}
```

```html
Function 3: Hack speak<br>
<textarea id="sentence2" class="try"></textarea><br>
<button onclick="hackerSpeak()">Convert!</button>
<div id="replaceThree"></div>
```

Comment: you never reassign `milk` or call `break;`

Comment: Sounds like `counting==sentence2.value` is never `true`.  Now would be a great time to use your browser's debugging tools.  Place a break point in your code and step through it line by line as it executes.  What are the values of `counting` and `sentence2.value`?  Do they change over time?  When do you expect them to be equal and why?

Comment: `if(counting==sentence2.value){` should be `if(counting==sentence2.length){`

Comment: `if(counting==sentence2.value){` should be `if(counting==sentence2.value.length){` Effectively you want to test if the current position has reached the end of string. So use length property of strings that return the length pf the string

Comment: `sentence2` already contains the value, you don't need to write `sentence2.value`.

Comment: JavaScript strings can't be modified in place. You need to assign the result of `.replace()` back to the variable.

Comment: The first argument to `replace()` is not a position, it's a string to search for and replace.

Comment: Instead of `while(milk)` use `while(true)` and then use `break;` when you want to stop the loop.

Comment: @Sai Paladugu, I slightly modified the script in my answer when using loop approach since in the special case of an empty string, it goes into infinite loop. I have taken care of this special case with a minor change in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making it too complex. The `replace` method in JavaScript does not take an index as a parameter, but has the following parameters: `string.replace(searchvalue, newvalue)`.

And there is no need to use a loop to do what you are after.

You are trying to use replace by passing the index of a character in a string which is not supported by replace method.

**Simple solution without using a loop**

Instead, to meet your requirements, you should use following script.

```
 Function 3: Hack speak<br>
    <textarea id="sentence2" class="try"></textarea><br>
    <button onclick="hackerSpeak()">Convert!</button>
    <div id="replaceThree"></div>


 <script>
 function hackerSpeak(){
  var sentence2 = document.getElementById('sentence2').value;
  document.getElementById('replaceThree').innerHTML = sentence2.replace("a","4").replace("e","3");
 }
 </script>
```

**Another solution using a while loop**

If you still had to use a loop then modify your code to what is given below. A demo can be seen at [running demo](https://js.do/sun21170/stackoverflow-infinite-loop)

Note that with a loop approach you have to re-construct a sentence character by character starting from the first character in original sentence. The variable `newSentence` will be constructed one character at a time using the business rules you have. This approach uses string concatenation when adding each character to newSentence value.

```
Function 3: Hack speak<br>
    <textarea id="sentence2" class="try"></textarea><br>
    <button onclick="hackerSpeak()">Convert!</button>
    <div id="replaceThree"></div>



 <script>
 function hackerSpeak(){
  var sentence2 = document.getElementById('sentence2').value.trim();
  var milk = false;
  var counting = 0;
  var newSentence = "";
  while(milk === false){
  if(sentence2.length == 0 || counting > (sentence2.length -1)){
     milk = true;
  }
  else if(sentence2.charAt(counting)==="e"){
     newSentence =  newSentence + "3";// sentence2.replace(counting, "3")
     counting++;
  }
  else if(sentence2.charAt(counting)==="a"){
     newSentence =  newSentence + "4";//sentence2.replace(counting, "4")
     counting++;
  }
  else{
    newSentence = newSentence + sentence2.charAt(counting);
    counting++;
   }
  }//end of while loop
  document.getElementById('replaceThree').innerHTML = newSentence;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code will become increasingly large and clumsy as new substitutions appear.

```
// array of characters to replace and their replacments - 
// easier to extend the array to include new values without 
// forcing code become more aware 
var hackerSwaps = [
    ['a', 'e', 'o'],    // n00bspeak
    ['4', '3', '0']     // 1337sp34k
];

// args to function are id properties of sentence and output target
 function hackerSpeak(sId, outId) {
    // convenience reference 
    function get(eId) {return document.getElementById(eId);};

    // split sentence into character array
    var s = get(sId).value.split('');
    // for each pair of items in the character swapping array
    for (var j = 0; j < hackerSwaps[0].length; j++) {
        var c = hackerSwaps[0][j];  // get n00b char
        var h = hackerSwaps[1][j];  // get 1337 replacement
        // for each character in sentence
        for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            if (s[i] == c) s[i] = h;
        }
    }
      // convert back to String and write to page
      get(outId).innerHTML = s.join('');
};
```

And for the HTML...

```
    <form>
            <textarea id="sentence2" class="try">some content with 'a' and 'e' characters</textarea><br>
            <input type="button" onclick="hackerSpeak('sentence2', 'replaceThree');" value="Convert!" />
            <div id="replaceThree">nothing</div>
    </form>
    <p id="replaceThree"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem which i could see is exiting the while loop. Instead
of using sentence2.value you can compare it with sentence.length

try the below code for exiting

```
if(counting==sentence2.length){
     milk = true;
  }
```

even in the replace function, it not works with the indexing, you can use

```
if (sentence2.charCodeAt(counting) == "e") {
      sentence2.replace("e", "3")
      counting++;
    } else if (sentence2.charCodeAt(counting) == "a") {
      sentence2.replace("a", "4")
      counting++;
    } else {
      counting++;
    }
```

once the counter is updated, it will match for the length of sentence2 and exit the loop.

Comment: There are lots of other problems, see the comments.